# One model for POST and GET with different "required" field

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-swagger

I use `go-swagger`. I have model like:

```
// Pet pet
// swagger:model
type Pet struct {
    // id
    ID int64 `json:"id,omitempty"`
    // name
    // Required: true
    Name *string `json:"name"`
}
```

and for example in my **POST** field `Name` have to be **required** but for **GET** not. So how should I add it if I don't want create similar model without required? Because for now my only thought is to create `type PetGET struct` and `type PetPOST struct` which, I guess is stupid idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating spec from code, then having a PetGET and PetPOST is not a stupid idea. Usually the program model doesn't match the API model, and you have to repeat definitions just to generate the spec right. So you have a couple of options here:

You can simply mark the field `required: false`, and deal with it in the GET handler.

If you're generating spec from code, you can create swagger-only models separate from your program models, and for cases like this, create two models with different annotations.

Comment: And if now I want `default` only for **PUT** I have to create another model?

Comment: If you want *that* level of precision in your model, then yes. Or, use the model for GET, and define the body inline for PUT/POST without a separate model struct.